# MediaPlayer reproduce solo los primeros segundos de mi audio android studio con kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, mediaplayer

Estoy intentando reproducir un `.mp3` de fondo para un activity pero el audio solo dura 2 o 3 segundos y se detiene cuando en realidad el `.mp3` dura `1 min 3 seg`. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.suspenso)
        mp.setVolume(100F, 100F)
        mp.start()
    }
```

Comment: Si le cambias al evento onStart() te da el mismo problema?

Comment: Seguramente el problema es el archivo "suspenso", Implementa el listener OnErrorListener para saber especificamente cual es el error,saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de buscar y probar varios ejemplos he encontrado la solución.

> Para que `MediaPlayer` funcione correctamente necesita estar inicializado fuera del contexto de una función, como si fuera una propiedad de la clase.

Si nos fijamos en mi código, la inicialización de `MediaPlayer` se encuentra dentro del método `onCreate`. ¡Gran Error!

**La solución es la siguiente:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.musica_de_fondo)
        mPlayer?.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: En realidad **también debe funcionar inicializando el MediaPlayer dentro de onCreate()**, si no funcionaba en realidad el problema es tu archivo. No necesitas declararlo fuera de onCreate.

Comment: En teoría funciona, pero solo unos segundos, ahí es cuando el audio se detiene. Si el audio a reproducir es de baja duración da la sensación de que todo funciona bien.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que describes "dura 2 o 3 segundos y se detiene", **si no finaliza la reproducción el problema seguramente es el archivo de audio, probablemente tiene un error**, especificamente debes asegurar que usa los codecs adecuados

[Android: Formatos compatibles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats)

**Para verificar específicamente cual es el erro, te sugiero usar el listener `OnErrorListener`**, en donde puedes imprimir y verificar que tipo de error obtienes cuando ocurre algún error.

```
        mp!!.setOnErrorListener { mp, what, extra ->
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ocurrio un error reproducción mp: ${mp}\nwhat: ${what}\nextra: $extra" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            false
        }
```

así mismo te sugiero también usar el listener `OnCompletionListener`, el cual te indicará cuando termino completamente la reproducción del archivo de medios.

```
    mp!!.setOnCompletionListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Finaliza reproducción",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

#### ¿Kotlin: Como reproducir audio usando MediaPlayer?

```
        val mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.suspenso)
        mp!!.setOnPreparedListener {
            mp.setVolume(100F, 100F)
            mp.start()
            Log.i(TAG, "Inicia reproducción")
        }
        mp!!.setOnCompletionListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Finaliza reproducción",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.i(TAG, "Finaliza reproducción")
        }
        mp!!.setOnErrorListener { mp, what, extra ->
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ocurrio un error reproducción mp: ${mp}\nwhat: ${what}\nextra: $extra" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.i(TAG, "ERROR mp: ${mp}\nwhat: ${what}\nextra: $extra")
            false
        }
```